# MSI PS42 8RB-035 Ubuntu compatibility

Tags: compatibility, msi

With no result after googling about it, I'm trying to figure it out if the new MSI PS42 8RB-035 is fully compatible with Ubuntu. Is there someone running Linux on the machine who could give me a feedback ?

Here is the spec : https://fr.msi.com/Laptop/PS42-8RX/Specification or https://www.ldlc.com/fiche/PB00253598.html

To complete my question, it's not about how to empirically know about ubuntu compatibility in general but how to know cutting edge hardware compatibility where there is no information yet, precisely on the machine I gave in exemple.

Comment: What do you mean by "as employee's computer"?  Also, that does not appear in the list of machines submitted to Canonical https://certification.ubuntu.com/catalog/category/SYSTEM/?&page=22 which have passed Ubuntu compatibility tests, but it will probably work anyway; make a LiveUSB and try it yourself.

Comment: Well sorry if it was misleading, by employee's computer I just wanted to say that it would not be a personal computer. For sure I'll try LiveUSB in case I got this machine in hand and will let people know.

Comment: FYI: Fully compatible Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, 3 fingers gesture seems to not work though.

Comment: @onepix thanks for posting your results! Were there any issues at all during installation? Does the dedicated graphics behave nicely? HDMI works etc?